# Acceleration of fluid in a magnetohydrodynamics vortex

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration, navier-stokes, vortex, magnetohydrodynamics

In the following video we see a mercury vortex done by magnetohydrodynamics:
https://youtu.be/au4hbUm4mMo

In the following manuscript they say that the fluid will accelerate according to (14) ${}^1$:
[https://ceas.iisc.ac.in/~bsreeni/jfm02.pdf](https://ceas.iisc.ac.in/%7Ebsreeni/jfm02.pdf)

Or:

$ a = (J \times B) / \rho $

Where:

$ J $: current (A)

$ B $: magnetic field (T)

$ \rho $: linear mass density of the fluid (kg/m)

Am I correct? What about the viscosity of the fluid?

**EDIT**

$ J $: current flux (A/m^2)

$ B $: magnetic field (T)

$ \rho $: volume mass density of the fluid (kg/m^3)

${}^1$ Experimental study of a vortex in a magnetic field, by Binod Sreenivasan and Thierry Alboussiere, Department of Engineering, University of Cambridge, Trumpington Street, Cambridge CB2 1PZ, UK

Comment: I think **$j$** is current flux $A/m^2$ and $\rho$ is usual density $kg/m^3$.  And this magnetic force term is probably meant to be one more term in the Navier Stokes momentum equation, alongside the usual viscosity term ~$\mu \nabla ^2 u$

Comment: Correct about what?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v5): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of links, so it is possible to reconstruct links in case of link rot.

C